# Exercises in FOL

Tags: first-order-logic

From Section 4.2 of "An introduction to mathematical logic" By Richard Hodel.

I would appreciate comments on how to proceed with exercise $(3)$ and whether $(4)$ is correct:

20. > Express these syllogisms in the language of FOL and in each case decide whether the syllogism is valid or invalid.

$ (3)$ $(i)$ No wheelbarrows are comfortable vehicles. $(ii)$ No uncomfortable vehicles are popular. $\therefore$ No wheelbarrows are popular.

*soln.*
$(i)$  $\forall x[W(x) \to \lnot C(x)]$ $\equiv \forall x[\lnot W(x) \lor \lnot C(x)]$
$(ii) \forall x [\lnot C(x) \to \lnot P(x)]\equiv \forall x (C(x) \lor \lnot P(x))$
$\therefore \forall x [W(x) \to \lnot P(x)]\equiv \forall x (\lnot W(x) \lor \lnot P(x))$

I'm stuck with drawing conclusion now:
Since in $(i), (ii)$ there are $\lnot C(x)$ and $C(x)$ respectively, we are left with $\lnot W(x)$ and $\lnot P(x)$ from $(i)$ and $(ii)$. So we have $\lnot W(x) \land \lnot P(x)$. But we need $\lnot W(x) \lor \lnot P(x)$.

$(4)$ $(i)$ Some healthy people are fat. $(ii)$ No unealthy people are strong. $\therefore$ Some fat people are not strong.

$(i)$ $\exists x(H(x) \land F(x))$
$(ii) \forall x (\lnot H(x) \to \lnot S(x))\equiv \forall x( H(x) \lor \lnot S(x)).$
$\therefore \exists x(F(x) \land \lnot S(x)).$

From $(i)$ I know that $(H(x) \land F(x))$ is true, so both relations here must be true for particular $x$.
For $(ii)$ there is $H(x)$ as well, but for all $x$. Since here logical operation is $\lor$, $\lnot S(x)$ can be either $T$ or $F$ for $(ii)$ to be true.
Thus putting $(i),(ii)$ together: $\exists x[(H(x) \land F(x)) \land \lnot S(x)] \lor [(H(x)\land F(x)) \land S(x)].$

Therefore initial syllogism $\exists x(F(x) \land S(x))$ is not valid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In $(3)$ you actually do get the desired conclusion. I don’t know exactly what formal derivational rules are available to you, so I’ll reason informally. Let $x$ be arbitrary, and suppose that $W(x)$. Then (*i*) tells you that $\neg C(x)$, at which point (*ii*) tells you that $\neg P(x)$. In other words, $\forall x\big(W(x)\to\neg P(x)\big)$. In both steps I’m using the tautology $\big((p\lor q)\land\neg p\big)\to q$.

In $(4)$ you don’t know that $H(x)\land F(x)$ is true: you know that there is at least one entity $c$ such that $H(c)\land F(c)$ is true. I don’t know whether you’re permitted to use this approach, but I’d show that the syllogism is invalid by producing a counterexample. Suppose that there is exactly one person, $c$, in the universe of discourse, and that $F(c)$, $H(c)$, and $S(c)$ are all true. Clearly (*i*) is satisfied, since $H(c)\land F(c)$ is true. (*ii*) is vacuously satisfied, since $\neg H(x)$ is false for all $x$ (in the universe of discourse). Finally, $F(c)\land\neg S(c)$ is false, so there is no $x$ (in the universe of discourse) such that $F(x)\land\neg S(x)$ is true. Thus, it is consistent that (*i*) and (*ii*) hold, but the conclusion does not.